# How to disallow concurrent executions of the same Pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I know the resource_group, it works at a job-level but not at the pipeline level. Is there pipeline-level concurrency control in Gitlab-CE for non cross-project/parent-child pipelines?

Jenkins offers the `disableConcurrentBuilds` option, but Gitlab does not provide such a simple solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, GitLab doesn't offer an analog to Jenkins' `disableConcurrentBuilds`. As you mentioned, the `resource_group` option does something similar, but would have to be configured for all jobs on the pipeline accessing the "resource".

Parent/child pipelines have [pipeline-level concurrency controls](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/resource_groups/#pipeline-level-concurrency-control-with-cross-projectparent-child-pipelines) but normal pipelines do not.

The only workaround without using parent/child pipelines or resource groups might be to implement this yourself by using a pipeline job with custom logic (say, by checking the project pipelines API) and fail the pipeline early if another pipeline is already running.

```yaml
concurrency_check:
  stage: .pre  # always run in the first stage of the pipeline
  script:  # pseudo-code
    - |
      if another_pipeline_running; then
          echo "another pipeline is already running"
          exit 1
      fi
```

It is also possible to limit job concurrency on a self-hosted *runner*, using the [`concurrent` parameter](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html) ensuring only one job runs at a time, but it does not guarantee jobs between pipelines are not interleaved.